# error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Hi
 I got one error, the error message is like 
/IphoneTextFieldViewController.h:13: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token

actually am not getting why it shows in this way and i have to post below the code and line number 13 in .h file ({- this colon line shows error), plese help me on this one

Thanks in advance

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface IphoneTextFieldViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;

    NSString *String;

}
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet NSString *String;



-(IBAction)changrGreeting;
{                                13: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token





    self.String=textField.text;
    NSString *nameString=String;

    self.String=textField1.text;
    NSString *nameString1=String;

    if ([nameString length]== 0)
    {
        nameString = @" ";
    }

    if([nameString1 length]== 0)
    {
        nameString1=@" ";
    }

    textField2.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",textField.text,textField1.text];

}

@end
```

.m file

```
//
//  IphoneTextFieldViewController.m
//  IphoneTextField
//
//  Created by Span on 1/31/11.
//  Copyright __MyCompanyName__ 2011. All rights reserved.
//

#import "IphoneTextFieldViewController.h"
#import "IphoneTextFieldAppDelegate.h"

@implementation IphoneTextFieldViewController

@synthesize textField;
@synthesize textField1;
@synthesize textField2;
@synthesize String;

-(IBAction)changrGreeting;
{
    self.String=textField.text;
    NSString *nameString=String;

    self.String=textField1.text;
    NSString *nameString1=String;

    if([nameString length]==0)
    {
        nameString=@" ";
    }

    if([nameString1 length]==0)
    {
        nameString1=@" ";
    }

    textField2.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ %@",textField.text,textField1.text];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

}




/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [textField release];
    [textField1 release];
    [textField2 release];
    [String release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 5):

.h file must be look like

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface IphoneTextFieldViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;

    NSString *String;

}
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet NSString *String;

-(IBAction)changrGreeting;
```

and in .m

```
-(IBAction)changrGreeting
{
    self.String=textField.text;
    NSString *nameString=String;

    self.String=textField1.text;
    NSString *nameString1=String;

    if([nameString length]==0)
    {
        nameString=@" ";
    }

    if([nameString1 length]==0)
    {
        nameString1=@" ";
    }

    textField2.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ %@",textField.text,textField1.text];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the ; before the {...

it should be

```
 -(IBAction)changrGreeting{
```

Secondly remove the method definition from the interface... Just keep method declaration...

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

why do you have implementation in your interface (.h)?

```
{
    self.String=textField.text;
    NSString *nameString=String;
    self.String=textField1.text;
    NSString *nameString1=String;
    if ([nameString length]== 0)
    {
        nameString = @" ";
    }
    if([nameString1 length]== 0)
    {
        nameString1=@" ";
    }
    textField2.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",textField.text,textField1.text];
}
```

this doesn't belong there. Delete it.

and delete the `;` behind `-(IBAction)changrGreeting;` in your implementation (.m)

Comment: Actually, the `;` in the .m file is harmless. Try it--the compiler ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen happen if you're copy and pasting method names from somewhere else. For instance when im building frameworks whose API's Id like to be congruent with Apples I will often look up the class(es) in question and just copy the "Tasks" section as a starting point. The problem with this is that some sites, like Apples documentation, will display an EN DASH rather than the hyphen that the compiler is expecting.